# How to make Opencart 1.5.6 urls use product name

Tags: php, sql, seo, opencart

Currently when you choose a product (Business cards) the url looks like this

http://smoothprint.co.uk/index.php?route=product/category&path=59

What would I have to change so the Url would be

http://smoothprint.co.uk/business-cards

Is the url saved in the database attached to the product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally I would mark Your question as an Off Topic as it is hell clear You did not use GOOGLE before asking here... As there are many tutorials (and I believe also some similar questions regarding this here on SO).

1. First of all You would have to go to Your OC  and rename `htaccess.txt` file to just `.htaccess` (yep, with the dot in the front)
2. Second, go to Your administration -> *System* -> *Settings* -> click edit Your store and on tab *Server* (I guess) You'll find option *Allow SEO friendly URLs* (or something similar) - **check the checkbox** and hit on *Save*
3. Now You can walk around the administration of categories, products, informations and manufacturers and all of these have an option **SEO keyword** (when editing/inserting one) - this field then is used for Your fancy SEO URLs...

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed tutorial about this: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/opencart-how-to-enable-and-use-seo-urls.html

Remember that just will not leave your site more "optimized" for SEO. Include [data-vocabulary](http://www.data-vocabulary.org/), unique descriptions, and internal links.